# how to add trigger to count number of rows automatically after inserting in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to add trigger to count number of movies after inserting!

This is the table to store the count value:

```
CREATE TABLE mov_count
  (mcount NUMBER);
```

and the movie table:

```
create table movie
  (mov_id number primary key,
   mov_title varchar(20),
   mov_lang varchar(20));
```

This is the trigger I have created:

```
create trigger count_movie_trg
after insert on movie
for each row
BEGIN

  UPDATE mov_count
  SET    mcount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movie);

END; 
/
```

After creating this i tried to add movie but its showing mutating trigger/function may not see it error.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not create a view that shows the count? This way, you don't need to worry about how to keep the count up-to-date.

Comment: Because i have to include any one triggers in my dbms mini project : )

Comment: Ok. Just so long as you understand that this would be a poor design decision in a real, production database (what if two or more sessions try to insert/update etc. at the same time? You'll potentially end up with wrong data in your table.) *{:-)  For the learning of triggers, it's a bit contrived, but should fulfill the learning requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `FOR EACH ROW` that bothers you. It is a table-level trigger, so:

Enter a dummy value for beginning (as you'll update it later):

```
SQL> insert into mov_count values (0);

1 row created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger count_movie_trg
  2    after insert on movie
  3  begin
  4    update mov_count c set
  5      c.mcount = (select count(*) from movie m);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into movie
  2    select 1, 'Titanic' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Superman' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select count(*) from mov_count;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome. However, think it over: perhaps you'd rather collect that data when you need it (for example, using a view) than maintaining it via database trigger.

Comment: ok! but i have to include triggers in dbms mini project,so im using triggers!!

Comment: No problem with me, just saying.

Comment: if u don't mind,can you answer my another question which i just asked!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just maintain the value without referring to the original table?

```
create trigger count_movie_trg after insert on movie for each row
begin
    update mov_count set mcount = mcount + 1;
end;
```

To keep the count up-to-date, you'll need a `delete` trigger as well.

Comment: thank you! can i add after insert or delete on movie? to keep it up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the table at all; use a view instead.

```sql
CREATE VIEW mov_count ( mcount ) AS
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movie;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5f73906a6a4b383276312b9128d52c3)